# How do I subtract an R,G,B of 25 at all the pixels where this watermark appears in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, watermark, video-editing

- I have a video with a watermark on it for the full duration.
- I have figured out that I need to subtract R,G,B of 25 from those pixels where the water mark appears
- How can I do this with ffmpeg?

[image]

Comment: If you can make a mask image (black background and white where you want 25 subtracted), you could run it through a few lines of Python to do the subtraction...

Comment: I can see how you can use an overlay image to add to certain pixels but subtracting doesn't appear to be an option. My next thought is *"well, can we add a black image that is -25 where you want to subtract 25"* so I'm wondering about an image format that can store -25, and TIFF can do that. So that would be my idea... use `ffmpeg` to add a TIFF that is zero everywhere and -25 where you want to subtract.

Comment: Mmm... not sure if `ffmpeg` will accept images with negative pixels - `float` maybe?

Comment: Convert to RGB. Crop out a portion containing the logo. Use geq filter to subtract 25  Use alphamerge to attach a alpha of the logo. Then overlay on full frame with the right coordinates. Convert back to YUV.